# Get full path to file from FileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I update database from excel using FileUpload (ASP .NET).

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="File1" runat="server" Text="File..."/>
```

When I'm using IE11 I can get path to file from PC. But I can't get path to file when I'm using Chrome (Opera). How can i get a full path from FileUpload?

I try get path:

```
 //get full path   
 string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(file.PostedFile.FileName);
```

but it is work only with IE.

Comment: As Rainman says, you can't if the user is using any other browser than IE.

Comment: as Rainman said its not possible. but what do you want to do with the path?

Comment: If you want tto do something with the file itself and not the path there are ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need the full path of client I don't know, but you can't retrieve client file path. Because, modern browsers don't provide that information for security reasons. Imagine that, if you get the full path, it would give you some critical informations about the client and its file system or network mapping.

**So, it is not possible**. Also, i don't know maybe there is a setting on browsers to give upload path information even so only the client must decide it to provide this information.

Comment: I am sorry, but your answer has the format of a comment. You have enough reputation to post it as such